# Selecting columns from a hive/sql table dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, hive

I am a newbie in hive and equally newbie in sql as well. So In case I am implementing my solution in an inappropriate manner, please enlighten me.

[image: Table Structure]

My application takes ID as input from user. Then I need to check the Pname values corresponding to it in Table1, and then based on pname's value, need to fetch corresponding column from Table2.

In other words i need a query like this:
`SELECT (SELECT Pname FROM Table1 WHERE ID=1) FROM Table2 WHERE ID=`1;

Is such an operation possible in Hive? If not, what alternative solution I can try implementing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the table2 to this form(table3):

```
ID  Pname  Pval
1   par1   10
1   par2   15
```

and so on.

And then using the join like

```
select table1.*, table3.pval
from table1 join table3 
on table1.id = table3.id and table1.pname = table3.pname
```

If you dont know how to construct table3.Here is my solution.

```
select id, pname, pval
from table2 lateral view 
explode(map('par1', Par1, 'par2', Par2, 'par3', Par3)) t as pname,pval
```

So final sql is

```
select table1.*, table3.pval
from table1 join (
select id, pname, pval
from table2 lateral view 
explode(map('par1', Par1, 'par2', Par2, 'par3', Par3)) t as pname,pval)
table3 
on table1.id = table3.id and table1.pname = table3.pname
```

At last you can put your where in the end if you only want to get one id's records.